# How is $r$ used in vector equation for plane?

Tags: vector-analysis

How is $r$ used in vector equation for plane?

Since the equation is:

$$r \cdot n = a \cdot n$$

And the $r$ is a variable that remains in the final equation. But what is it used for?

Comment: Do you know what $a,n,$ and $r$ stand for ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust $a$ is the position vector of the known point $P_0$. $n$ is the given normal vector to the plane. $r$ is the position vector of some unknown point $P$. So $r$ is a parameter that defines any point on the plane? So it's the variable that we're solving for?

Comment: Yep, that's it. The equation specifies all possible values for $r$ (as there is a single equation, there is a double infinity of choices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets rename $a$ to $r_0$, just to use the same letters as most literature, and also the linked pictures.

If you write your equation like $$(r-r_0)\cdot n=0$$ the equation is much more intuitive.

That equation is the so called normal form of a plane. All vectors $r$ that fulfill that equation define your plane.

Here is a picture that illustrates everything that follows. Look at it wihle reading through the rest of this answer.

[image]([Source](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/EqnsOfPlanes_files/image001.gif))

The vector defined by $(r-r_0)$  is the vector "from $r_0$ to $r$", as you can see in the picture. In the picture the vector $r$ is on the plane, so the red vector "lies exactly in the plane".

If the vector $r$ would be located below or above the plane, the red vector $(r-r_0)$ would "point out of the plane".

That property can be translated to "the red vector $(r-r_0)$ should be orthogonal to $n$".

And that is exactly what the scalar product $$(r-r_0)\cdot n\overset{!}{=} 0$$ does.

The reason is simple if we look at the (geometrical) definition 
$$x\cdot y = |x||y|\cos(θ),$$
with $|x|$/$|y|$ being the length of vector $x$/$y$ and $θ$ being the angle between $x$ and $y$. 
If these two vectors are orthogonal it is $θ=90°$, and $x\cdot y=0$. Otherwise the scalar product is not $0$.